# Finding an element repeating n times in 2n size array. Will this solution work?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I have an array which has 2n elements where n elements are same and remaining n elements are all different. There are lot of other complex algorithms to solve this problem.

**Question:** Does this approach give the same result or I am wrong somewhere?

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int arr[10],i,res,count=0;
    printf("Enter the array elements:\t");
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==arr[i+1] || arr[i]==arr[i+2])
         {
             res=arr[i];
             break;
         }
        else if(arr[i+1]==arr[i+2])
        {
            res=arr[i+1];
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        if(arr[i]==res)
           count++;
    if(count==5)
        printf("true, no. repeated is:\t%d",res); 
    else printf("false");    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to failing for the trivial 2 element case, it also fails for 4 elements in this case:

```
a b c a
```

I think the easiest way to solve this problem is to solve the majority element problem on `a[1] ... a[2*N-1]`, and if no majority is found, then it must be `a[0]` if a solution exists at all.

One solution to the majority element problem is to scan through the array counting up a counter whenever the majority candidate element is encountered, and counting down the counter when a number different from the candidate is encountered. When the counter is 0, the next element is automatically considered the new candidate.

If the counter is positive at the end of the scan, the candidate is checked with another scan over the array. If the counter is 0, or the second scan fails, there is no majority element.

```
int majority (int a[], int sz) {
  int i, count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
  int candidate = -1;
  for (i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
    if (count1 == 0) candidate = i;
    count1 += ((a[candidate] == a[i]) ? 1 : -1);
  }
  if (count1 > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
      count2 += (a[candidate] == a[i]);
  }
  if (count2 <= sz/2) candidate = -1;
  return candidate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm will fail when the array has only 2 elements. It does not handle trivial case